# ORA-01403: no data found during online table redefinition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

> ORA-01403: no data found during online table redefinition in oracle
>   when trying to convert basicfile lob to securefile lob.

Steps followed:

1. Created table T1 with basicfile lob (stored in tablespace ts1) having primary key on number field.
2. Loaded the table T1 with data.
3. Created interim table T2 with same structure as T1 (lobs being Securefile stored in tablespace ts2)
4. Perform Online redefinition (with copy_indexes => 0) to convert T1 to 
   securefile lob.
5. ORA-01403: no data found in copy_table_dependents.

I have tried setting copy_indexes --> 1 which does not result in any error

```
SQL> @online_redef.sql   sf sf basic_table sf_table sf/sf@cdb1_pdb1 'sys/knl_test7@cdb1_pdb1 as sysdba' 'tbsbas.dbf' 'tbsinter.dbf'
SQL> SET FEEDBACK 1
SQL> SET NUMWIDTH 10
SQL> SET LINESIZE 80
SQL> SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SQL> SET TAB OFF
SQL> SET PAGESIZE 100
SQL> 
SQL> SHOW CON_NAME

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB1_PDB1
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Create a new user
SQL> DROP USER &1 CASCADE;
old   1: DROP USER &1 CASCADE
new   1: DROP USER sf CASCADE
DROP USER sf CASCADE
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'SF' does not exist


SQL> CREATE USER &1 IDENTIFIED BY &2;
old   1: CREATE USER &1 IDENTIFIED BY &2
new   1: CREATE USER sf IDENTIFIED BY sf

User created.

SQL> 
SQL> -- Grant privileges
SQL> GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO &1;
old   1: GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO &1
new   1: GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO sf

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE SESSION TO &1;
old   1: GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE SESSION TO &1
new   1: GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE SESSION TO sf

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER TABLESPACE, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, DROP TABLESPACE TO &1;
old   1: GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER TABLESPACE, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, DROP TABLESPACE TO &1
new   1: GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER TABLESPACE, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, DROP TABLESPACE TO sf

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO &1;
old   1: GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO &1
new   1: GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO sf

Grant succeeded.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Connect as user
SQL> CONNECT &5
Connected.
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Create tablespace for storage of BasicFiles
SQL> DROP TABLESPACE &3 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
old   1: DROP TABLESPACE &3 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
new   1: DROP TABLESPACE basic_table INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
DROP TABLESPACE basic_table INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'BASIC_TABLE' does not exist


SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE &3
2      DATAFILE '&7'
3      SIZE 256M REUSE
4      EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
5      UNIFORM SIZE 4M
6      SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
old   1: CREATE TABLESPACE &3
new   1: CREATE TABLESPACE basic_table
old   2:     DATAFILE '&7'
new   2:     DATAFILE 'tbsbas.dbf'

Tablespace created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Create tablespace for storage of interim table.
SQL> DROP TABLESPACE &4 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
old   1: DROP TABLESPACE &4 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
new   1: DROP TABLESPACE sf_table INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
DROP TABLESPACE sf_table INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'SF_TABLE' does not exist


SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE &4
2      DATAFILE '&8'
3      SIZE 256M REUSE
4      EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
5      UNIFORM SIZE 4M
6      SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
old   1: CREATE TABLESPACE &4
new   1: CREATE TABLESPACE sf_table
old   2:     DATAFILE '&8'
new   2:     DATAFILE 'tbsinter.dbf'

Tablespace created.

SQL> 
SQL> --Translate BasicFile to SecureFile
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TranslateBasicToSecure( schemaName IN VARCHAR2,
2      originalTableName IN VARCHAR2, interimTableName IN VARCHAR2) IS
3  redefinition_errors PLS_INTEGER := 0;
4  BEGIN
5      -- Check whether table can be redefined
6      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking if table can be redefined');
7      DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(schemaName, originalTableName);
8  
9      -- Attempt a redefinition mapping.
10      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Attempting to start redefinition');
11      DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE (
12           uname => schemaName,
13           orig_table => originalTableName,
14           int_table => interimTableName,
15           col_mapping => NULL,
16           options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_PK
17      );
18  
19      -- Copy data
20      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Copying table dependents');
21      DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS (
22           uname => schemaName,
23           orig_table => originalTableName,
24           int_table => interimTableName,
25           copy_indexes => 0,
26           copy_triggers => TRUE,
27           copy_constraints => TRUE,
28           copy_privileges => TRUE,
29           ignore_errors => FALSE,
30           num_errors => redefinition_errors,
31           copy_statistics => FALSE,
32           copy_mvlog => FALSE
33      );
34  
35      IF (redefinition_errors > 0) THEN
36          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Migration errors: '
37              || TO_CHAR(redefinition_errors));
38      END IF;
39  
40      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sync Interim Table');
41      DBMS_REDEFINITION.SYNC_INTERIM_TABLE(schemaName,
42          originalTableName, interimTableName);
43  
44      -- Complete the redefinition process
45      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Finish redefinition process');
46      DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE (
47           uname => schemaName,
48           orig_table => originalTableName,
49           int_table => interimTableName
50      );
51  
52      EXCEPTION
53          WHEN OTHERS THEN
54              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception Caught!!');
55              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error : ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
56              DBMS_REDEFINITION.ABORT_REDEF_TABLE (
57                   uname => schemaName,
58                   orig_table => originalTableName,
59                   int_table => interimTableName
60              );
61  
62  END;
63  /

Procedure created.

SQL> SHOW ERRORS;
No errors.
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Create sequence to generate unique id's
SQL> DROP SEQUENCE seq;
DROP SEQUENCE seq
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist


SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Table containing BasicFile
SQL> DROP TABLE &3 PURGE;
old   1: DROP TABLE &3 PURGE
new   1: DROP TABLE basic_table PURGE
DROP TABLE basic_table PURGE
         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> CREATE TABLE &3 (
2       cnt        NUMBER,
3       cdata      CLOB,
4       bdata      BLOB,
5       prevcmb    VARCHAR2(500),
6       currentcmb VARCHAR2(500),
7       id         NUMBER DEFAULT seq.NEXTVAL
8  )
9      LOB(cdata)
10          STORE AS BASICFILE (TABLESPACE &3),
11      LOB(bdata)
12          STORE AS BASICFILE (TABLESPACE &3),
13      PARTITION BY RANGE (cnt)
14       SUBPARTITION BY HASH(id)
15      SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (&3, &3, &4, &4)
16        (PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
17         PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (40),
18         PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (60));
old   1: CREATE TABLE &3 (
new   1: CREATE TABLE basic_table (
old  10:         STORE AS BASICFILE (TABLESPACE &3),
new  10:         STORE AS BASICFILE (TABLESPACE basic_table),
old  12:         STORE AS BASICFILE (TABLESPACE &3),
new  12:         STORE AS BASICFILE (TABLESPACE basic_table),
old  15:     SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (&3, &3, &4, &4)
new  15:     SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (basic_table, basic_table, sf_table, sf_table)

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> ALTER TABLE &3 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BASIC PRIMARY KEY(cnt);
old   1: ALTER TABLE &3 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BASIC PRIMARY KEY(cnt)
new   1: ALTER TABLE basic_table ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BASIC PRIMARY KEY(cnt)

Table altered.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Table containing LOBs stored as SecureFile
SQL> DROP TABLE &4 PURGE;
old   1: DROP TABLE &4 PURGE
new   1: DROP TABLE sf_table PURGE
DROP TABLE sf_table PURGE
         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> CREATE TABLE &4 (
2       cnt        NUMBER,
3       cdata      CLOB,
4       bdata      BLOB,
5       prevcmb    VARCHAR2(500),
6       currentcmb VARCHAR2(500),
7       id         NUMBER DEFAULT seq.NEXTVAL
8  )
9      LOB(cdata)
10          STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE &4),
11      LOB(bdata)
12          STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE &4),
13      PARTITION BY RANGE (cnt)
14       SUBPARTITION BY HASH(id)
15      SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (&3, &3, &4, &4)
16        (PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
17         PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (40),
18         PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (60));
old   1: CREATE TABLE &4 (
new   1: CREATE TABLE sf_table (
old  10:         STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE &4),
new  10:         STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE sf_table),
old  12:         STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE &4),
new  12:         STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE sf_table),
old  15:     SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (&3, &3, &4, &4)
new  15:     SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (basic_table, basic_table, sf_table, sf_table)

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Populate table containing BasicFile
SQL> DECLARE
2      cnt NUMBER;
3      dataBlob BLOB;
4  BEGIN
5      FOR cnt in 1..5 LOOP
6          INSERT INTO &3(cnt,cdata,bdata) VALUES (cnt,
7              dbms_random.string('a', round(dbms_random.value(low=>10,high=>4000))),
8              EMPTY_BLOB())
9              RETURNING bdata INTO dataBlob;
10          LoadBFile('T_WORK', 'tklolobdata.dmp', dataBlob);
11      END LOOP;
12  END;
13  /
old   6:         INSERT INTO &3(cnt,cdata,bdata) VALUES (cnt,
new   6:         INSERT INTO basic_table(cnt,cdata,bdata) VALUES (cnt,

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SHOW ERRORS;
No errors.
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &3;
old   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &3
new   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM basic_table

COUNT(*)
----------
       5

1 row selected.

SQL> 
SQL> CONN &6
Connected.
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT SECUREFILE FROM dba_lobs WHERE table_name = upper('&3');
old   1: SELECT SECUREFILE FROM dba_lobs WHERE table_name = upper('&3')
new   1: SELECT SECUREFILE FROM dba_lobs WHERE table_name = upper('basic_table')

SEC
---
NO
NO

2 rows selected.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Translate table containing BasicFile to SecureFile
SQL> exec TranslateBasicToSecure('&1','&3','&4');
Checking if table can be redefined
Attempting to start redefinition
Copying table dependents
Exception Caught!!
Error : 100 - ORA-01403: no data found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> -- Verify if table is copied
SQL> SELECT SECUREFILE FROM dba_lobs WHERE table_name = upper('&3');
old   1: SELECT SECUREFILE FROM dba_lobs WHERE table_name = upper('&3')
new   1: SELECT SECUREFILE FROM dba_lobs WHERE table_name = upper('basic_table')

SEC
---
NO
NO

2 rows selected.

SQL> SQL>
```

Expected Result: Basicfile lob to be converted to Securefile lob.

Actual Result: Error : 100 - ORA-01403: no data found
SECUREFILE field in dba_lobs for the table after redefinition is 'NO'

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a full demo? I can't replicate your error. Here's my top to bottom

```
SQL> create table T1 ( x int, y clob, t timestamp default systimestamp, constraint T1_PK primary key (x) )
  2   lob (y) store as basicfile ( tablespace users );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t1 (x,y)
  2  select rownum, rpad(rownum,4000)
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 100;

100 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> create table T2 ( x int, y clob, t timestamp default systimestamp )
  2   lob (y) store as securefile ( tablespace largets );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> EXEC DBMS_REDEFINITION.can_redef_table(user, 'T1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table(user, 'T1', 'T2');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_num_errors PLS_INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_REDEFINITION.copy_table_dependents(
  5      uname             => user,
  6      orig_table        => 'T1',
  7      int_table         => 'T2',
  8      copy_indexes      => DBMS_REDEFINITION.cons_orig_params,
  9      copy_triggers     => TRUE,  -- Default
 10     copy_constraints  => TRUE,  -- Default
 11     copy_privileges   => TRUE,  -- Default
 12     ignore_errors     => FALSE, -- Default
 13     num_errors        => l_num_errors);
 14    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_num_errors=' || l_num_errors);
 15  END;
 16  /
l_num_errors=0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_REDEFINITION.sync_interim_table(user, 'T1', 'T2');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_REDEFINITION.finish_redef_table(user, 'T1', 'T2');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```